# how to group rows but only on non disjointed date ranges in sql server t-sql

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, group-by, row-number

I am importing a subset of records and columns from a source table to a local table. I am trying to collapse the data so that I can have unique rows in my table, but only when the date ranges are consecutive. I am having trouble as I can't figure out how to do the grouping such that I don't jump over date ranges. Here is some sample data:

```
|PID | GroupID | Data | StartDate | EndDate
| 12 |       1 |    4 |        45 |      50
| 11 |       1 |    5 |        40 |      45
| 10 |       1 |    5 |        35 |      40
| 9  |       1 |    4 |        30 |      35
| 8  |       2 |    5 |        25 |      50
| 7  |       1 |    4 |        25 |      30
| 6  |       1 |    4 |        20 |      25
| 5  |       1 |    2 |        15 |      20
| 4  |       1 |    3 |        10 |      15
| 3  |       1 |    3 |         5 |      10
| 2  |       2 |    1 |         1 |      25
| 1  |       1 |    2 |         1 |       5
```

I am trying to get this result:

```
|GroupID | HistoryID | Data | StartDate | EndDate
|      1 |         1 |    4 |        45 |      50
|      1 |         2 |    5 |        35 |      45
|      1 |         3 |    4 |        20 |      35
|      1 |         4 |    2 |        15 |      20
|      1 |         5 |    3 |         5 |      15
|      1 |         6 |    2 |         1 |       5
|      2 |         1 |    5 |        25 |      50
|      2 |         2 |    1 |         1 |      25
```

So imagine there are thousands of group ids, the `data` column is actually multiple columns and start/end date are actual dates.

What I was trying to do is some kind of solution by self joining on `startDate` and `endDate` and comparing data, or doing some kind of `partion by groupid` and grouping on data. Then taking the minimum `startDate` and maximum `endDate`. However, I cant figure out a way to do it such that data 4 doesn't go from 20 startdate to 50 enddate and overlap the date range for data 5.

I know in Sql Server 2012 there is new stuff for lookahead rows and running totals but I'm implementing in Sql Server 2008. Any ideas?

Comment: While it is possible to do this in sql, it tends to be a lot easier to do this in post-processing in whichever programming language you use - you would have to do several joins in sql.

Comment: yeah, im sure i could do it lots of ways including by hand, but the solution I need is t-sql. I imagine it involves a couple common table expressions and some clever usage of the group by and rank or row_number functions. I just cant quite figure it out yet. I have out lined the parameters of the problem and the desired solution. preferably no solutions invlolving cursors.

Comment: Can be gaps between ranges? For example there are two ranges 20-25 30-35 and there is no range 25-30? If so, can records be in one group if they have a gap between ranges?

Comment: each group id represents an object with its own time dimension the time dimension  has no gaps, for each object the records are consecutive and non disjointed. each object has its own time line goign back from current to some date int the past.

Answer (score 1):

If gaps between ranges are not possible, or if they don't break a group then:

```
    ------------
-- test data
------------
declare @data table
(
    Pid int,
    GroupID int,
    Data int,
    StartDate int,
    EndDate int
)

insert into @data (Pid, GroupID, Data, StartDate, EndDate)
values 
(10, 1, 4, 45, 50),
(9, 1, 5, 40, 45),
(8, 1, 5, 35, 40),
(7, 1, 4, 30, 35),
(6, 1, 4, 25, 30),
(5, 1, 4, 20, 25),
(4, 1, 2, 15, 20),
(3, 1, 3, 10, 15),
(2, 1, 3, 5, 10),
(1, 1, 2, 1, 5)


-----------
-- solution
-----------
select
    GroupID, Data, StartDate = min(StartDate), EndDate = max(EndDate)
from
(
    select 
        *, 
        rn1 = row_number() over(order by StartDate), 
        rn2 = row_number() over(partition by GroupID, Data order by StartDate desc) 
    from @data
) t
group by GroupID, Data, rn1 + rn2
order by StartDate desc
```

otherwise, please let me know.

Comment: very clever with the date asc and desc. rn1 needs partition by groupid and the final select needs rownumber partitioned by groupid to create the historyid column(groupid , historyId become the new primary key) and filtering by historyid = 1 is my quick and easy select from my new table for all groups most current record. but otherwise this solution worked great, thanks Alexey